Upgrade to 6.5.0-35 kernel broke bluetooth
I just upgraded my computer to the latest apt packages including 6.5.0-35-generic kernel, and bluetooth is gone. If I boot back to 6.5.0-28, bluetooth works as it always has.  Anyone else having this issue? Any suggestions?
syslog from from 6.5.0-35 startup:
Jun  7 10:30:15 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth Support.
Jun  7 10:30:15 shorton-SEiBeelink bluetoothd[740]: Terminating
Jun  7 10:30:15 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    7.473053] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    7.473073] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    7.473075] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    7.473079] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    7.473083] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    7.473087] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink bluetoothd[715]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth Support.
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink bluetoothd[715]: Starting SDP server
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    8.625122] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    8.625126] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    8.625148] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink bluetoothd[715]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1717774422.7785] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jun  7 10:33:42 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Jun  7 10:33:43 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    9.541190] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version command failed (-110)
Jun  7 10:33:43 shorton-SEiBeelink kernel: [    9.541188] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
Jun  7 10:34:08 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1366]: Starting Bluetooth OBEX service...
Jun  7 10:34:08 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1366]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
Jun  7 10:35:48 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth Support.
Jun  7 10:35:48 shorton-SEiBeelink bluetoothd[715]: Terminating
Jun  7 10:35:48 shorton-SEiBeelink systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Jun  7 10:35:48 shorton-SEiBeelink bluetoothd[715]: Stopping SDP server
Jun  7 10:35:48 shorton-SEiBeelink bluetoothd[715]: Exit


What you experienced simply happens sometimes. Something in the new kernel just is not right for your machine. That is why the OS keeps the old kernel so you can choose it if you need to. On boot from Grub choose Ubuntu advanced options and choose the last kernel, as you have done.

It may help if you tell us what release; you mention a 6.5 kernel, so which of the two releases using it are you using?  If using the HWE kernel stack (6.5) a workaround maybe switching kernel stacks for example (and still use a supported kernel as multiple stacks can be installed)

Does this help?   Working bluetooth kernel is:    Linux shorton-SEiBeelink 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux    Non-working bluetooth kernel is: Linux shorton-SEiBeelink 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

You've provided kernel details, and not what Ubuntu product/release you're actually using.  The detail does make it look like you're using a HWE kernel though; so GA kernel stack maybe an option (depending on your unstated product/release details)

I have the same problem, but with 6.8.0-35. Bluetooth had been working fine, now broken.

I investigated further, using command-line tools (sudo service bluetooth status,
hciconfig, and bluetoothctl (with subcommands), all of which indicated that Bluetooth was in fact up and running but with no devices found. I think I tried Blueman "make discoverable" along with more attempts with the pairing buttons on my mouse and kb. Finally they showed up and I was able to re-pair both. They are working again. So the kernel update didn't exactly break Bluetooth; rather, it caused it to forget about my devices, which had never happened before.
